# How to remove a list within list based on len in python?

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have the following input list

```
A = [['A',[1,2,3]],['D',[3,4]],['E',[6,7]],['F',[1]]]
```

I want to have sublists whose length is 2. 
In the above example, I want to remove [A,[1,2,3]], [F,[1]] etc
I am creating a new list and appending all sublists whose length ==2.
If I can directly remove from A, the unwanted sublists, it would be ideal

Comment: The ``len( ['A',[1,2,3]])`` is 2 as is the len of ``len(['F',[1]])``. Should we presume you mean the sum of lens or something else. As it is all you sublists are ``len == 2`` if the missing ]'s are put in imagined place ? Also the missing ]'s  I suspect one was meant to close off ``['E',[6,7]``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should't it be like this?

```
A = [x for x in A if len(x[1]) == 2]
```

Or even

```
A = [[a, b] for a, b in A if len(b) == 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use filter.

```
filter(lambda x: len(x[1]) == 2, A)
```

This assumes each of the element (list) has 2 elements, and the second element is a list. You want to filter the elements which have exactly 2 elements in this inner list.

More on filter:

> **filter(...)** 
>       filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string
>
> ```
> Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.
> ```

---

The same can be achieved via a list comprehension:

`[x for x in A if len(x[1]) == 2]`

Answer (score 1):

It's better and easier to create a new filtered list. `A[:] = ...` is a slice assignment which means that the content of the new list is copied back into `A` so that other references to the same list will see the update. If you don't need to keep the identity of `A`, you can just use `A = ...`

```
>>> A = [['A',[1,2,3]],['D',[3,4]],['E',[6,7]],['F',[1]]]
>>> A[:] = [x for x in A if len(x[1]) == 2]
>>> A
[['D', [3, 4]], ['E', [6, 7]]]
```

Removing in place is usually inefficient because you need to move the remaining items down the list each time you remove one. You also need to take care to not skip over elements when you remove from the list you are iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [x if len(x)==2 for x in A]
```

fyi, your E and F lists don't have closing brackets, but I'm assuming that's just a copy/paste error or similar.